# Why isn't css active definition working when the page moves from localhost to server?

Tags: python, css, flask

This is for a Flask-based site using Python.

I have a navigation menu, and I want the active state to change appearance. Here is the code from the CSS file:

```
/* SIDENAVBAR */
nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

nav{
  text-align: left;
  top: 10px;
  width: var(--navWidth);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 1%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*background-color: var(--priColor);*/
}


nav a{
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

a:hover{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.active{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

When this runs on LocalHost, it behaves as expected: hovering activates the black background, which remains intact after clicking.

On the server, the hovering works fine, but the black background goes away after clicking. (So the hover state is working, but not the active state.)

Here is the heading from the main layout template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
```

The behavior is the same on Firefox and Safari. Why isn't the active state working on the server?

Comment: To show it active, the CSS class `active` must be present at the HTML element (or the DOM). The CSS file is not responsible for that, it is done by JavaScript or by the server-side if a new page is sent. First step: Find out what should add the CSS class to the element.